# Offline heat map with map background

Tags: python, matplotlib, offline, heatmap

I am trying to find if we can have background set (as 2D map) for a heat map ? Read data from a file and plot heat map (which is pretty simple) But in offline mode can we have the heat map imposed on the real map ?

Any useful suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a [heat map as the background for a geographical map](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) (which I think is what you are asking about) using [basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) and [imshow](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.imshow).

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',
            resolution='c',lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)

data = 100*np.random.rand(10,10)
m.imshow(data, interpolation = 'none')

plt.show()
```

[image: map with heatmap]

Comment: Looks like something I was looking for .. Thank you so much but I am getting an error when trying to run it. ` m = Basemap(width=12000000, height=9000000, projection-'lcc', resolution='c', lat_1=19.,lat_2=59,lat_0=50,lon_0=73.)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
`  required lat lon are: `19.997453, 73.789802`

Comment: how can the color map be changed for this?

Comment: Got it. Can use the argument 'cmap';.

Comment: Can the grid size be changed?