# python - Display heat map on a Matplotlib/Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a dataset of longitudes/latitudes as follows:

```
id,spp,lon,lat
1a,sp1,1,9
1b,sp1,3,11
1c,sp1,6,12
2a,sp2,1,9
2b,sp2,1,10
2c,sp2,3,10
2d,sp2,4,11
2e,sp2,5,12
2f,sp2,6,12
3a,sp3,4,13
3b,sp3,5,11
3c,sp3,8,8
4a,sp4,4,12
4b,sp4,6,11
4c,sp4,7,8
5a,sp5,8,8
5b,sp5,7,6
5c,sp5,8,2
6a,sp6,8,8
6b,sp6,7,5
6c,sp6,8,3
```

I want to display a heat map representing the density of points over a geographical map using Matplotlib/Basemap, using the code below (more or less based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163952/offline-heat-map-with-map-background%20this%20one)):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import cm as cmap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# input data
coords = np.loadtxt("testdata.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(2, 3))
lon = coords[:,0]
lat = coords[:,1]

# create map
m = Basemap(width=12000000, height=9000000, projection='lcc',
            resolution='c', lat_0=6, lon_0=4.)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)

# create heatmap
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(lon, lat, bins=20)

# plot map
##plt.clf()
m.imshow(heatmap.T, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap.jet)
plt.show()
```

However, the heat map is displayed but the map is not shown (see attached figure)[image: [enter image description here]

This looks the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244710/basemap-heat-error-empty-map%20this%20question), in which the map is displayed but not the heat map (however that solution was not very helpful to me).

Any hints?

Comment: Comment this line: `plt.clf()`, that instruction cleanses what you have drawn, that is, the map.

Comment: Yes, what a lack of attention from my part! Thank you very much!