# python - Numpy point to grid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataset of longitudes/latitudes as follows:

```
id,spp,lon,lat
1a,sp1,1,9
1b,sp1,3,11
1c,sp1,6,12
2a,sp2,1,9
2b,sp2,1,10
2c,sp2,3,10
2d,sp2,4,11
2e,sp2,5,12
2f,sp2,6,12
3a,sp3,4,13
3b,sp3,5,11
3c,sp3,8,8
4a,sp4,4,12
4b,sp4,6,11
4c,sp4,7,8
5a,sp5,8,8
5b,sp5,7,6
5c,sp5,8,2
6a,sp6,8,8
6b,sp6,7,5
6c,sp6,8,3
```

From such data, I want to generate a grid like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

which gives the number of data records in each cell of the grid, using variable "spp" as a categorical (grouping) factor.

From this grid, I thwn want to create a heat map, superimposed on a geographical map, so that I end up with something like the figure below.

[image]

I can see [how to plot a heatmap on a Matplotlib/Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555175/python-display-heat-map-on-a-matplotlib-basemap), but I could not figure out how to generate the grid from the point data. Also, it is important that I am able to choose the grid size, so that several different resolutions can be evaluated. I suppose that what I want could be achieved by either Numpy [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) or Scipy [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), but I could not make further progress in understanding how to use them.

Any hints, ideas, suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a requirements dump , not a specific programming issue. SO is only applicable to the latter. The former costs money. Please make an attempt to solve this on your own and come to SO when you have a specific question about a piece of code that you can't get to work.

Comment: Can't really understand the point of such harshness. There are *plenty* of questions without "a piece of code that don't work" -- and they are all politely answered. As of myself, over the years I have asked many questions providing code, but *this time* I have not been able to even devise anything workable so it would be pointless, if not ridicule, to add three or four lines of code just to presume I had done someting. Anyway, I'm not asking for a "ready-made answer", just for a few hints and tips. But I am sure that other, more polite, SO users will provide useful suggestions. Salud!

Comment: There are plenty of questions about code that does not work, but this question has no code, just vague descriptions. Forgive me if I am being harsh. I would like to help you write a good question, but there is a lot you will have to change to make it so. There is plenty of information on aligning things to a grid if you care to look. The fact that others, or even  you, have gotten away with asking inadequate questions does not excuse you doing it now.

Comment: The problem is more that there is no real problem description here. It's indeed a task. I wouldn't say that you necessarily need to provide any code in general but the logic of supplying a problem description will usually automatically lead to questions with code. If you stick to [ask], you will need to make the problem clear by stating what you have tried to solve the task. This will bring you to things like meshgrid. Now if you say that you do not understand them, that's too general, so instead you need to try to use them. This will lead to code, and that code will be needed inthe question.

Comment: That being said, if your search has been fruitless because of language issues, I recommend something along the lines of "binning latitude and longitude" here is the first result I got: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/114334-how-to-produce-bin-averaged-or-summed-latitude-and-longitude-grids. It uses matlab's accumarray function, which can usually be reproduced by numpy's add.reduceat. That should at least get you started.

Comment: There are *plenty of questions that have NO code at all*, of the type 'how do I do this or that'! If you are a heavy user of SO, you should know this very well because you would already seen many of such questions. And al of them are patiently and politely answered, sometimes a lot of times. I don't agree that my question is 'vague', as tried to provide as much information as possible to describe my problem. And what's the point of SO if I would look for answers anywhere else? By the way, I *have cared to look for* answers but could not have found any - that's why I am here asking!

Comment: Again, your question does not fit into the category of questions that get polite answers. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest explained it much better than I ever could. Instead of getting increasingly defensive, please try to step back and understand what we are telling you. It will lead to a much more satisfactory resolution for everyone.

Comment: Mind an important difference. If someone asks for something that has never been asked for before, the actual problem is implicetely clear simply from the fact that there isn't any answer yet. In such cases, people are happy to provide an answer because it is useful to know for a lot of people how to solve this task. Those are the questions you usually find when looking for solutions. What you are asking here is just a very special case of the general problem of gridding coodinates. It is by the way independent of matplotlib or visualization. So you cannot expect to have someone do your task.

Comment: If provide reasoned replies to your accusations is to be 'defensive', so there is not point to argue anymore with you. Indeed, if you have not an answer, I can't even understand the need for replying to me, to begin with (other than a useless showdown in typical  arrogance). Salud.

Comment: The point of replying is to help make your question answerable. I have already provided you with helpful information to get you started. It may not seem that way to you right now, but I would like to see you complete your task. This also happens to be an area in which I have a lot of domain expertise which I don't mind sharing. That is not the same as coding for you for free.

Comment: The idea of those comments is usually to help you write a better question, which can be answered. There is indeed a good portion of idealism in from our side, trying to have only good and useful questions on SO. There are also other mechanisms in place for that purpose, namely to close questions as "too broad" or "off-topic". Eventually, the review queue will decide on its faith. A final remark: Don't take any of this personal and see it free of emotions. And if you have doubts about anything or want to hear different opinions, you may ask a question on [meta].

Comment: We'd like to help you maurobio, there is no doubt about that; how can you ask a question (maybe in smaller chunks) so it becomes workable for one of us to assist?

Comment: You, perhaps, @Reblochon Masque (as always, geography matters). But I cannot see how people who downvote my question, leading to its being deleted sooner or later, are willing to help me. Perhaps the question is not really very clear, because I have difficulty of explaining it in simple, non-technical terms. In short, what I want is to find (and plot) *biodiversity hotspots* given data on point occurrences of species in geographic space. This is called a "richness analysis" and is performed by one specialized GIS (DIVA-GIS). But I am sure it can be done in Python.

Comment: I understand what you are asking, but it is too wide a problem to help you with without a starting point. As far as downvoters are concerned, it it bothers you, you can delete this question, it will erase the votes. Then you can post a new modified question, building on the experience gained (yes, there is good advice, even in harshness...). Help us help you.

Comment: As a side note, you can very easily do this in ArcGIS. I would direct you to https://gis.stackexchange.com for details.

Comment: I can easily do this in DIVA-GIS, which is completely free and fully adequate for this particular task. However, it should be reason whiy I want to do it in Python, isn't it? And I am aware of gis.stackexchange - I also post questions there - including this one, where it has not been met by the mardi gras of arrogance it found here; Salud!

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://justpaste.it/1c0ga) helps you understand us better. It's just a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use pandas you could do something like this

```
dims = max(df[['lat','lon']].max())
df.groupby(['lat','lon'])['lat'].count().unstack().reindex(range(1,dims+1)).T.reindex(range(1,dims+1)).fillna(0).T
```

resulting in a square dataframe

```
lon   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13
lat                                                                 
1    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9    2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
10   1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
11   0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
12   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
13   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

you could always convert by to numpy with `df.values`

Comment: A straight answer at last! Thank you very much, @djk47463! I have nothing against pandas, although I'm not very used to it. Your answer seems to work and I'll try it with other data. An user in gis.stackexchange.com also provided a useful anwer (without pandas, therefore longer and more convoluted than yours; I'm currently digging into it too). *Thank you very much for your kind help* As you clearly demonstrate, harshness and diatribes in an Q&A site don't lead one anywhere. Salud!

Comment: @maurobio, no problem, glad to help you get moving in the right direction!